# LR(1) constructing DFA

Tags: parsing

Consider the following grammar, where $ [ \ ] \ | \ , \ $ are terminal symbols

$ 
\begin{eqnarray}
L \rightarrow [ \ ] \qquad(1) \\ 
L \rightarrow [ \ H\ T\ ] \qquad(2) \\ 
H \rightarrow L \qquad (3) \\
H \rightarrow L\ ,\ H \qquad (4) \\
T \rightarrow |\ L \qquad(5) \\
T \rightarrow \epsilon \qquad (6)
\end{eqnarray}
$

I went over the step to create the DFA for that grammar, and then building parsing table.

However, after creating those things, I cannot parse the string $ [\ [\ ]\ |\ [\ [\ ]\ ,\ [\ [\ ]\ ]\ |\ [\ [\ ]\ ]\ ]\ ] $
Here is the DFA:
[image: DFA]

```
Note: In state 11, the only lookahead is $
```

I think my problem is that I determined wrong lookahead for some DFA states. But I still don't know what's wrong here.

Can anyone give my some idea?

Comment: No body has any idea, or the way I asked the question has problem??

Comment: Just too much work for random passers-by to dig in and check...